# How to set status to a file on successful processing in manifest file?

Tags: shell

I have a manifest file (say with 10 file names) and when my job runs manifest file is processed line by line and 7 files are moved to a certain directory in a loop one by one.But next time when I want to move the remaining 3 files to that directory the job will fail as it will not get those 7 files which are already moved to the destination.
So, I was thinking of setting status to the files which are being processed as (moved and not moved). and on basis of the status it will either skip the file or will move the remaining file to the destination.
P.S.: Any other suggestion will be appreciated too.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. The solution may be as simple as `cp --force` or `mv --force`. You should post a [mcve].

Comment: MY job is written in such a manner that if it does not get all the file names in a manifest file given then it will fail the job. But since in my case say my job is stopped due to some issue after moving 7 files to the destination then the next time when I will run my job, it will again fail the job due to the 7 files which it didnt see in the source location as they are already moved. I dont want to fail my job in this case and want to move the remaining 3 files to the destination folder.